# value delete is not a member of slick.lifted.Query[T,T#TableElementType,Seq]

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, play-slick

I am currently playing around with Play and play-slick. The following code gives me an error

```
class GenericRepository(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  import driver.api._

  implicit val localDateTimeColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[LocalDateTime, Timestamp](
    d => Timestamp.from(d.toInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(0))),
    d => d.toLocalDateTime
  )

  protected trait GenericTable {
    this: Table[_] =>
    def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def createdAt = column[LocalDateTime]("created_at")
    def updatedAt = column[LocalDateTime]("updated_at")
  }

  protected class CrudRepository[T <: AbstractTable[_] with GenericRepository#GenericTable](private val tableQuery: TableQuery[T]) {
    def all = db.run(tableQuery.to[List].result)
    def create(obj: T#TableElementType) = db.run(tableQuery returning tableQuery.map(_.id) += obj)
    def delete(id: Long) = db.run(tableQuery.filter(_.id === id).delete)
  }
}
```

Error:

```
value delete is not a member of slick.lifted.Query[T,T#TableElementType,Seq]
```

I already googled a lot but no solution worked for me. For instance I tried replacing 'import driver.api.*' with 'import slick.driver.H2Driver.api.*' without any luck.

I am using Scala 2.11.7 with play-slick 2.0.2 and Play 2.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: From your pasted code I see now your problem.

Just change your definition to (I changed type parameters only):

```
protected class CrudRepository[E, T <: Table[E] with GenericRepository#GenericTable](private val tableQuery: TableQuery[T]) {
    def all = db.run(tableQuery.to[List].result)
    def create(obj: T#TableElementType) = db.run(tableQuery returning tableQuery.map(_.id) += obj)
    def delete(id: Long) = db.run(tableQuery.filter(_.id === id).delete)
  }
```

where `Table` is `slick.relational.RelationalProfile.API.Table`.

Then instantiate your `CrudRepository` in following way:

```
val crud = new CrudRepository[Redirect,RedirectsTable](Redirects)
```

Otherthan that it's looking good.

Comment: Also you may think if it makes sense for you to return `Future` from `CrudRepository` method. Such approach won't allow you to perform operations within transaction.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! Unfortunately this results in another error: http://pastebin.com/k2KDemM8

Apparently, Scala is not able to see that the driver imports for both classes are the same.

For me db.run always returns a Future, btw.

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer - it makes your code compile.

Comment: What version of Slick is this? I have no `slick.relational.RelationalProfile.API.Table` in Slick 3.1.0 (but the same issue).

Comment: Found it: <slick.driver.MySQLDriver>.profile.api.Table